# JQuery DatePicker add initial 'please select' value

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have managed to create a `DatePicker` control on [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/prJrp/1/) which strips down the control to display only the `month` and `year` ranges.

I need to now append a 'Please select' option to the top of the `select` lists - however they have no `IDs` or any way I'm aware of to push a value.

Could someone please help me wrap my brain around this?

From JSFiddle:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-next {
    display: none !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev {
    display: none !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-buttonpane {
    display: none !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-header {
    background: none!important;
    border: none!important;
}

.ui-datepicker-title {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

---

```
$('#startDate').datepicker({
            yearRange: "1900:c",
            changeDay: false,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM yy',
            onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month) {
                $("#startYear").val(year);
                $("#startMonth").val(month);
            }
        });
```

---

```
<div id="startDate"></div>
```

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that both are different dropdownlist.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar yes I am

Comment: so you want Please select in both the dropdown??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Yes please, I've updated my question to pluralize `list`

Comment: added the answer below

Comment: You use datepicker... then mangle it until it's just 2 dropdowns... why use datepicker at all?

Comment: So I don't have to set `select` lists with a bunch of dates.. Also, I don't have to have a `for` loop, nor do I have to customize an `onChange` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This On document ready:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-month").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'>Select Option</option>");

$(".ui-datepicker-year").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'>Select Option</option>");
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prJrp/2/)**

Comment: Selecting 1 dropdown vanishes the default text for other.

Comment: @Anup:it is baucause OP has used `onChangeMonthYear` option on datepicker.